# How do I run Windows 10 from the E-drive?

Tags: boot, multi-boot, drive-letter

**What I did**:
I have a multi-boot system, where I started with Windows 7, then added Win8.1, then Win10 and then Linux.
I do this because I want to. And because sometimes I want to test applications on different OSes, but mostly just because I want to.

I've done this on for separate partitions.
So, when I boot into  Win7 that partition becomes the C-drive, the Win8.1 is on the D-drive and the Win10 on the E-drive, Ubuntu is on the F-drive.

Now, the problem is, that when I boot into Win8.1, then that partition becomes the C-drive, the Win7 becomes the D-drive and the Win10 stays the E-drive, Ubuntu remains on the F-drive.
And as you probably know, whenb I boot into Win10, then THAT partition becomes the C-drive, the Win7 becomes the D-drive yet again and the Win8.1 is assigned to the E-drive, and Ubuntu remains on the F-drive.

This is not what I want.

**Question**:  I want the tree OSes to be assigned the same drive-letter, no matter what OS i boot into. So, Win8.1 remains on D-Drive and Win10 boots up as the E-drive. Is that possible and so, how? Also mention workarounds and that sort of stuff.

*What I tried*:

Re-assigning the drive letters, which didn't work. TBH i wouldn't know where to start

Comment: I'm pretty sure Windows enumerates on the fly, so C: is just going to dance around. This is why other OSes use the volume's UUID for recognition. Windows has stuck with this dozy drive lettering system about 20 years too long, imo.

Comment: are you saying it's not possible, no way no how??? :-( :-( :-( :-( :-( :-(

Has no-one even TRIED to do this??

Would extreme Virtual Disking help?

Comment: What exactly is “extreme virtual disking”?

Comment: Ah. That would be the well-known practice ;-) ;-) ;-) of have multiple virtual disk on your system, or virtual hard drives or virtual boxes... Think 5 or more.

PS
Yes, no. That's obviously not a well-known thing. But I've seen a case of 6 different VHD's. And a more serious set-up with a cross platform  game testing group...

Comment: VHDs need an OS to mount them & are better suited to Virtual Machines. You can't boot from them. tbh VM sounds like a far better bet to have as many OSes as you like, with zero conflicts.